# Unclear about management of XML structure using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to create a XML structure (not read/write from/to a file, only the logical part). I'm really confused about how to go about it and what do use. After looking on the Internet I've seen two candidate classes: `XmlDocument` and `XDocument` (with their corresponding references to nodes, elements, attributes etc.).

One's got to be deprecated but I've checked fairly recent posts (2010 and even 2011) and they are still suggesting code using both variants. Also, the Google check for `XDocument` only gives a fraction of the hits that `XmlDocument` brings.

When that part is sorted out, I've seen a number of different examples on how to compose a **very simple** XML structure. I guess the approach depends on the competence level of the person who suggests it, so I'm asking straight out - what classes and what syntax to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the very same issue a few weeks ago. Apparently, you can't trust numbers - `XmlDocument` gets roughly 20 times the count hit as `XDocument` **but** the former is deprecated and the latter is to be used.

As for the explanation to this phenomenon, I'm assuming that a lot of code was created using the deprecated class (and by that period's standards it was a **huge** convenience to use them). Years later, people are using "what's working" without realizing that there's a "new kid on the block".

And here's a simple example on how to create a logical XML structure.

```
XDocument xml = new XDocument(
  new XElement("main",
    new XElement("first", "---"),
    new XElement("second",
      new XElement("first sub", "---"),
      new XElement("second sub", "---"))
));
```

More on the subject can be read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of building XML documents: using a class holding the entire document in-memory or a one-way XML writer.

- [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) is the recommended way of building XML documents that could fit into the memory. It is not suited for very large XML files. `XmlDocument` is not yet marked as deprecated but I suspect it might become in future versions of the framework.
- [XmlWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) on the other hand is suited for building large XML documents that cannot fit into memory. Contrary to the `XDocument` this is a one-way writer and once a node is written you can no longer go back and modify it.

There's also a third way to build XML documents which falls into the first category and which is through XML serialization of .NET types. There are a couple of classes allowing you to achieve that such as [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) and [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx).

Comment: Oh, that was some heavy info. Luckily for me, I won't need to create a huge structure. It's more of a proof of concept thing. Never the less, It's a valuable response. How did you guys managed to type so quickly, by the way?! I hardly got my coffee and I've got two detailed replies (and one shorter, still good)...

Comment: @Retsmahc Well, we got our coffee machines on our desks, so there's no need to get up and waste time walking.

Answer (score 0):

There are differences in performance!

Read [Performance: LINQ to XML vs XmlDocument vs XmlReader](http://www.nearinfinity.com/blogs/joe_ferner/performance_linq_to_sql_vs.html)

Linq to XML is more faster than XmlDocument